# TypeScript Interface Array Type error TS2411

Tags: typescript

I'm having difficulty trying to understand this:

> There are two types of supported index types: string and number. It is possible to support both types of index, with the restriction that the type returned from the numeric index must be a subtype of the type returned from the string index.
>
> While index signatures are a powerful way to describe the array and 'dictionary' pattern, they also enforce that all properties match their return type. In this example, the property does not match the more general index, and the type-checker gives an error:
>
> ```
> interface Dictionary {
>     [index: string]: string;
>     length: number;    // error, the type of 'length' is not a subtype of the indexer
> }
> ```

source:[TypeScript Handbook's interface](http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces)

I have tried 4 cases, but still cannot understand what is happening. Would anyone explain why only `[index: string]: string;` will has error TS2411?
[image]

Another case:

[image: another case]

Comment: You missed one `codio@compact-guide`. I don't see a reason to hide it anyways

Comment: miss two exactly .....

Comment: Nice. Hiding it made me want to find out more :)

Answer (score 5):

if you have `[index: string]: string;` *all properties must be a `string`*. Hence:

```
interface Dictionary {
    [index: string]: string;
    length: number;    // error, length is not a string.
}
```

Comment: thanks, I am sorry for late reply. I am too foolish. I include one more test case in your answer, would you help me.

Comment: Sorry, but I am unclear which code sample you have a question about

Comment: sorry, I just add it.

Comment: That case is an error too if you try in the playground. You have an older version of tsc I suppose

Comment: it will has error only if I add one more line -->var foo:Dictionary=['peter','john']; <-- is it what you mean ^_^

Comment: sorry I organize my question again. I think my test case is  messing up. please ignore my previous comment

Answer (score 2):

A workaround with TypeScript 2.4 is

```
interface Dictionary {
    [index: string]: string | number;
    length: number;
}
```

However, you may need to cast explicitly when using

```
let v = dict.key as string
```

Answer (score 0):

> It is possible to support both types of index, with the restriction that the type returned from the numeric index must be a subtype of the type returned from the string index.

Also there is no question mark, the answer is No. This Array wont work in any way:

```
interface Dictionary {
    [index: string]: string;
    length: number;  // error
}
```

because even this will work:

```
interface Dictionary {
    [index: string]: string;
}

var dic: Dictionary = {}
dic[1] = "123"
```

Note that we are indexing the string array with a number.

`interface Dictionary { [index: string]: MYCLASS; }` is meant to support you to define the value allowed, but not the type of the Index, sorry

What you are doing is not about interfaces but arrays: http://www.typescriptlang.org/Handbook#interfaces-array-types